# PyLance giving "Code is unreachable" for BinanceSocketManager Websocket Usage

Tags: python, python-asyncio, pylance

PyLance giving `"Code is unreachable"` for `BinanceSocketManager` Websocket Usage

Is this a bug or this code is really not working?

```
async def main(coin):
    bm = BinanceSocketManager(client)
    ts = bm.trade_socket(coin)
    async with ts as tscm:
        while True:
            res = await tscm.recv()
            if res:
                frame = createframe(res)
                if frame.Price[0] < buyprice * 0.97 or frame.Price[0] > 1.005 * buyprice:
                    order = client.create_order(symbol=coin,
                    side='SELL',
                    type='MARKET',
                    quantity=buy_quantity)
                    print(order)
                    loop.stop()
    await client.close_connection() #This is the unreachable code
```

thanks for help.

Comment: if you run `while True` (without `break`) then it never exits this loop - and it can't run `close_connection()`

Comment: On a side note, you shouldn't assign a value to `type` as it's a built-in variable.